# For an invertible matrix $C$, when is $ACA^T$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $k \times n$ matrix of rank $k$ and $C \in GL(n)$. Fix $A$. When is the matrix $ACA^T$ invertbible? Meaning what are the relavent conditions (depending on $A$) on $C$ which makes $ACA^T$ invertible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a matrix $A \in M_{k \times n}(\mathbb{F})$, denote by $T_A \colon \mathbb{F}^n_{\mathrm{col}} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^k_{\mathrm{col}}$ the corresponding linear map defined using multiplication. Your question is equivalent to the question of finding conditions for the composite map $T_{A^t} \circ T_C \circ T_A \colon \mathbb{F}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^k$ to be invertible. We have

$$ \mathbb{F}^k \xrightarrow{T_{CA^t}} \mathbb{F}^n \xrightarrow{T_A} \mathbb{F}^k. $$

We want the map $T_{CA^t} \circ T_A$ to be onto so the map $T_A$ must be onto. Thus, as you wrote, we must have $k \leq n$ and $\mathrm{rank}(A) = k$. The other condition we must impose is that $\mathrm{im}(T_{CA^t}) + \ker(T_A) = \mathbb{F}^n$. For example, if $k = n$ then $C$ must be invertible.